# Linux gcc picking trying to instantiate a template where function should be

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc

I have the following sample code that reproduces my error:

```
// non-namespacing this compiles as expected
namespace n
{
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T const & t)
    {
        t.doesnt_have_this_method();
    }
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T const & t)
{
    // picks the template over the overload
    n::foo(t);
}

namespace n
{
    // function overload
    void foo(int const &);
}

void n::foo(int const &) {}


int main()
{
    int a;

    bar(a);
}
```

That code compiles fine on both MSVC 2010 and Solaris 8 compilers.
But gcc4 (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42) fails with the error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'void n::foo(const T&) [with T = int]':
test.cpp:14:   instantiated from 'void bar(const T&) [with T = int]'
test.cpp:34:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:6: error: 'const int' has no member named 'doesnt_have_this_method'
```

The template `bar` doesn't seem to see the `foo` function overload. I want to figure out why this is happening. Three things that I know can alleviate the issue, but are difficult to enforce in a production environment:

1. declaring `foo(int const &)` before `bar`. This is something that I can do in my prod code, but is difficult to enforce throughout the entire codebase in the future
2. not putting `foo` in a namespace. This is something that I can't do because I am interfacing with another library.
3. making the overload a template specialisation `template<> void n::foo(int const &)`. Something that I can't do, because the declaration of `foo(int const &)` is out of my control.

Please help me understand on how to fix this. Why isn't the compiler picking the right function?

Comment: gcc and clang are both right, MSVC and Solaris are not...

Comment: You should use a newer GCC. [4.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.1/) is from 2006. Current one is [GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/) and 5.0 will be released in spring 2015.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am afraid that is out of my control. We have to use that compiler.

Comment: @ForEveR do you have any references to back that up?

Comment: @SergeyL. not now... I'm trying to digging standard...

Comment: In general, the only way something from the template instantiation context (as opposed to the definition context) can be picked up is via ADL, and there is no ADL for `int`.

Comment: There's also no ADL for qualified calls.

Comment: interestingly, EDG compiles the code in C++03 mode, but not C++11 mode

Comment: "This is something that I can do in my prod code, but is difficult to enforce throughout the entire codebase in the future" -- Is this compilation with GCC a one-time event? If you regularly use a compiler that implements templates correctly, then it seems easy to enforce: you can easily point out that a specific change breaks the build.

Comment: @hvd This is the first time in our codebase that `bar` has been implemented and used. I can make it work for this instance, but future use may be limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the definition of `bar` the only `foo` that is visible is the function template, because the other one hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: Depending on the version of the standard you are using, `n::foo` may not even be a dependent name since it's a *qualified-id*.

Comment: Oh good point ... I forgot that. I've removed the std quote for name resolution of dependent names, since it's not relevant. http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1321 changed that